# Mongo Db $in query with multiple keys

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo db collection of documents which contains **_id** , **version** and many other fields. I have an array of id's like :

```
["1A", "2b", "3C", "4D"]
```

If I want all the documents that contain any of the above id's, i could query like :

```
{
  _id : {
         $in: ["1A", "2b", "3C", "4D"]
        }
}
```

I'd like to know if we can query with another condition in addition to the **_id** i.e the above array with condition, something like below :

```
{
      $in: [{"id":"1A","version":"1.1"},{"id":"2B","version":"2.1"},{"id":"3C","version":"3.1"},{"id":"4D","version":"4.1"}]
        }
}
```

Example for **{"id":"1A","version":"1.1"}** : 
I want all the documents that has **id as 1A** and **version as 1.1**. Similarly for all the objects in the array.

Comment: What is your question? Please rewrite question with better example.

Comment: @Saleem Sorry for the missing clarity. I've edited the question. Hope it is understandable now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
 db.collection.find(
   {
     //this OR will make sure that you get at any matching combination
     $or:[
       {"<FIELD1>": "<VALUE1.1>", "<FIELD2>": "<VALUE1.2>"},
       {"<FIELD1>": "<VALUE2.1>", "<FIELD2>": "<VALUE2.2>"}
     ]
    }
 )
```

The documentation of above **$and** is available [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).

Also there are other operators as well, like **$or**, **$not**, [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will look for ids and versions seperately and "and" them. My problem is , each id i.e your "FIELD1" has its specific corresponding version i.e your "FIELD2".

Comment: Thanks  for that. That is one solution to make a single query for all the combinations. I can loop through my array and build this query,  but my question is if there is a possibility to do that without "AND"ing each combination i.e have all the combinations in a single query.

Comment: Updated the answer and I am 99% sure you will accept this. Just kidding. 
;)

Answer (score 2):

Showing example with two values. You can add as many you need. Make use of $or and $and operators for multi keys.

```
find({
    "$or": [{
        "$and": [{
            "_id": "1A"
        }, {
            "version": "1.1"
        }]
    },{
        "$and": [{
            "_id": "2B"
        }, {
            "version": "2.1"
        }]
    }]
})
```

Update to include the search in the object arrays.

Sample Collection:

```
db.multikeys.insertMany([{
    _id: 1,
    tags: [{
        _id: "1A",
        version: "1.1"
    }, {
        _id: "2B",
        version: "1.4"
    }]
}, {
    _id: 2,
    tags: [{
        _id: "2B",
        version: "2.1"
    }, {
        _id: "3C",
        version: "3.1"
    }]
}])
```

Query:

```
db.multikeys.find({
    tags: {
        $elemMatch: {
            $or: [{
                _id: "2B",
                version: "2.1"
            }, {
                _id: "1A",
                version: "1.1"
            }]
        }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Sample Output:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "tags": [{
        "_id": "1A",
        "version": "1.1"
    }, {
        "_id": "2B",
        "version": "1.4"
    }]
} {
    "_id": 2,
    "tags": [{
        "_id": "2B",
        "version": "2.1"
    }, {
        "_id": "3C",
        "version": "3.1"
    }]
}
```

Comment: This won't work properly when filter is happening against a array of item. Give a try and see for yourself

Comment: I know. but OP didnt mention anything about searching in the array. I'll wait for OP to confirm and change it accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't work. I have an array of objects like mentioned in the question in which each object has an id and version. I want to check if there are any documents that satisfies both of those values in each object. I want the document only if that id matches with the corresponding version. This is same like $in except i have two values to check instead of one.

Comment: Please take a look now. Updated based on my understanding. Hope it helps. you can use $in operator too instead of $or I think.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to match both the criteria like

```
db.collection1.find(
   { arrayObjectKeyName: { $elemMatch: { id: "1A", version: "1.1" } } }
)
```

Sure, here is an example of such

```
db.collection1.find({ "arrayObjectKeyName": {"$elemMatch":{"id": "1A","version":{"$in":["1.1","1.3","1.9876"]}  }} })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But to do this, i have to query with each "id" seperately. Instead I want to be able to do a single query like i did "$in" for array of id's.

Comment: @suzo, No, you can as well use the `$in` operator in `$elemMatch`

Comment: Exactly, i was just wondering how we can do that. Can you please help me on that?

Comment: Thanks for the edit but it doesn't work. Please see the above comment in Veeram's answer